# AngularJS, Getting error when trying to use $resource

Tags: angularjs

My code: http://plnkr.co/edit/2blxwwyv0gS9GYui7IVn?p=preview

I defined a service:

```
angular.module('jsonService', ['ngResource']).factory('JsonService', function($resource) {

     var jsonService = $resource('data.json/:id',
          {id: "@id"}, //parameters default
          {
            getAll: { method: "GET", params: {} },
            addNew: { method: "POST", params: { id: ":id"}},
          });
     return jsonService;

  });
```

I keep getting error when I try to call `getAll` from my `controller`.
I also tried to add a new object but `AddNew` simply would not work from the `controller`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `isArray: true`

```
getAll: { method: "GET", params: {}, isArray: true },
```

Please take a look at ***actions*** parameter from [$resources](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource).

> isArray – {boolean=} – If true then the returned object for this
>   action is an array, see returns section.

And this is how to post data

> non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData,
>   [success], [error])

For example:

```
var obj = { "id": "2", "created": "3424324", "updated": "2342666", "name": "Bob" };
JsonService.addNew({ "id": "2"}, obj)
```

Comment: Thanks man, can you tell me also how to add an object using the resource with AddNew I added in my controller this command `{
        "id": "2",
        "created": "3424324",
        "updated": "2342666",
        "name": "Bob"
    }` and it is not working

Comment: @Canttouchit, you can do `JsonService.addNew({ "id": "2"}, obj)`

Comment: My bad: http://plnkr.co/edit/2blxwwyv0gS9GYui7IVn?p=preview, well still not working

Comment: @Canttouchit That will call your API to update not updating the json file. you have to implement the actual API to handle that

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that there is no way to avoid testing adding an object without implementing some sort of server?